# File .webp in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm tryin to minify .webp files in webpack.config.js.
Here it's the code:

```
    mode: 'development',

    module: {
        rules:[
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options:{
                        'presets': ['@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                test:  /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader:             'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name:           '[name]-min.[ext]',
                            outputPath:         'assets/images',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "image-webpack-loader",
                        options: {
                            mozjpeg: {
                                progressive:    true,
                                quality:        20,
                            },
                            // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
                            optipng: {
                                enabled:        true
                            },
                            pngquant: {
                                quality:        [0.65, 0.9],
                                speed:          4
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced:     false
                            },
                            // the webp option will enable WEBP
                            webp: {
                                quality:        10,

                            },
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    entry: './App',
    output: {
        path:           path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        filename:       '[name].bundle.min.js'
    }
```

In the folder "dist" i see all files, correctly minified, except the .wepb image where the quality is the same of the original (i created a folder "images" where i loaded a png, a jpeg and a webp)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.